# Visual Studio 2017 - select certificate from Store not working

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017, I want to select a certificate from the local store (in 'Signing' tab on project properties).
However, As soon as I click the 'Select from Store...'  button, a dialog pops up: 'Windows Security' - 'Select a Smartcard' with a few options, none of which make sense to me. To make matters worse: when I cancel this dialog, it just pops up again. The only way to exit this, is to kill Visual Studio from the task manager.

On another machine (with the same project), the 'Select from Store...' option works as expected. 
Can anyone explain what is going on (and how to solve this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem (and solution). Just in case anyone experiences the same:

On my machine in my personal certificate store, there where several different (old) certificates stored for which the private key was held on a hardware smartcard.
Those smartcards where not present (it would be physically impossible for them all to be present unless I would have several seperate card readers).

It seems that when Visual Studio look in the certificate store, it requires that the private keys for all certificates are accessible (even for non code signing certificates) before presenting the choice of suitable certificates.
If not a bug, this certainly seems like stupid behaviour to me...

Solution: in the personal certificate store, remove all certificates that have their private key on a hardware token that is not physically present.